# Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference. Why this error?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am working on a project in Visual Studio 2019 using Visual Basic and whenever I try to switch from one form to the other I get 2 errors. The first one is just "Sub Main" was not found in "[Project Name]". The second one is the "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference". I'm assuming this is like a "Hey you're trying to call to something that you didn't create?" sort of thing but I am just trying to do a form switch with "Me.Hide()" and "(LoginForm.Show)" and the form IS created so?... Anyways any and all help would be appreciated thank you!

Here's the code:

```
Public Class WelcomeForm
    Private Sub WelcomeForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub GroupBox1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub GroupBox1_Enter_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Hide()
        LoginForm.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your question is tagged `visual-studio` and `visual-studio-code`. Which is it? What .Net version is your Solution targeting? Is it .Net 5? If that's the case, build another Solution that targets .Net Framework 4.8. You'll probably find it more *familiar*.

Comment: I apologize I'm new to this. If you're referring to the target framework in my project settings it would be .Net Core 3.1.

Comment: Bad choice. Either build a standard .Net Framework Solution (.Net Fx 4.8), or a .Net 5+ one. You probably want the former (until you get the hang of the latter, at least).

Comment: May I know why 4.8 and 5 work here when 3.1 isn't? Also, can I find those version in the installer or is it pre-included and all I have to do is create a new project and click 4.8-5?

Comment: .Net 5+ is the evolution of .Net Core 3.1 and it's based on it (many still call it `.Net Core`). The WinForms port to .Net Core 3.1 is partial an will never be fixed (there's no reason), .Net 5+  is the .Net version that matters. -- .Net Framework 4.8 is part of Windows 10, everyone has it. If you also need to support Windows 7, add the `<supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}" />` key in app.manifest (`<compatibility><application>` branch) and build an installer that lists .Net Fx 4.8 as pre-requisite. -- In Visual Studio Installer you can select/add any of these frameworks.

Comment: Thank you very much it seems to be working great so far!